# Degree of a field extension over $\mathbb Q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> I have to find the degree of the field extension $\mathbb Q(2^{1/2}, 2^{1/4}, 2^{1/8})$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Hope to get a elaborate answer. (I am very much new to field extension, so I would like to see the steps and understand them, which will help me in future.)
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

$\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/8})$ already contains $2^{1/4}$ and $2^{1/2}$ so you do not need to include those. The minimal polynomial for $t=2^{1/8}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ is $t^8-2=0$. The Eisenstein test confirms that it's irreducible. Hence, elements $\{1,t, t^2, \ldots, t^7\}$ are linearly independent and form a basis of your extension over $\mathbb{Q}$  which means its degree is $8$.

Comment: Everything is fine in the answer except the 1st line. I think Q[2^1/8]={a+b×2^1/8:a,b are rationals}, from here I can't understand how √2,2^1/4 belongs to the set.Will you please explain ?.

Comment: By definition Q(2^1/8) is the minimal field containing Q and 2^1/8 as a real number. Since fields are closed under multiplication, all powers of 2^1/8 are also included. The set you defined above is not a field and not even a ring - it's not closed under multiplication.

Comment: I got it, it is due to the field property. Thanks @Max for your answer

Comment: Wait ! Then how does Q(2^1/8) looks like ?

Comment: Like {a0+a1*2^1/8+a2*2^2/8+...+a7*2^7/8}, where all ai are rational.

Comment: Got it.. Actually I misunderstood with the structure of Q[√2],now it's clear.